# conditionally mutate new column with lowest date in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

**Data:**

```
library(data.table)
ALPHA_DEF<-c("ABCD","EFGH")

DT<-data.table(
      ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L),
   C_OPR = c("ABCD01", "ABCD11", NA, "EFGH", NA, NA, "KLMN", NA),
   D_OPR = c(NA, NA, "PQRST", NA, "EFGHIJ", NA, NA, NA),
    DATE = c("2002-02-02","2005-05-05","2001-01-01",
             "2003-03-03","2004-04-04",NA,"2001-01-01",NA))


DT

 ID  C_OPR  D_OPR       DATE
1:  1 ABCD01   <NA> 2002-02-02
2:  1 ABCD11   <NA> 2005-05-05
3:  1   <NA>  PQRST 2001-01-01
4:  2   EFGH   <NA> 2003-03-03
5:  2   <NA> EFGHIJ 2004-04-04
6:  2   <NA>   <NA>       <NA>
7:  3   KLMN   <NA> 2001-01-01
8:  3   <NA>   <NA>       <NA>
```

**Desired output:**

```
   ID  C_OPR  D_OPR       DATE ALPHA ALPHA_MIN_DATE
1:  1 ABCD01   <NA> 2002-02-02     1     2002-02-02
2:  1 ABCD11   <NA> 2005-05-05     1     2002-02-02
3:  1   <NA>  PQRST 2001-01-01     1     2002-02-02
4:  2   EFGH   <NA> 2003-03-03     1     2003-03-03
5:  2   <NA> EFGHIJ 2004-04-04     1     2003-03-03
6:  2   <NA>   <NA>       <NA>     1     2003-03-03
7:  3   KLMN   <NA> 2001-01-01     0           <NA>
8:  3   <NA>   <NA>       <NA>     0           <NA>
```

**Logic:**

Any C_OPR or D_OPR containing ALPHA_DEF per ID is shown in ALPHA. ALPHA_MIN_DATE is the lowest DATE (where C_OPR or D_OPR is TRUE in ALPHA_DEF)

**Attempt (without ALPHA_MIN_DATE):**

```
DT[, ALPHA := +any( grepl(paste0(ALPHA_DEF, collapse="|"),c(D_OPR, C_OPR)), by=ID]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(data.table)
library(collapse)
 DT[, ALPHA := +(Reduce(`|`, lapply(.SD, \(x)
  grepl(paste(ALPHA_DEF, 
      collapse = "|"), x)))), .SDcols = patterns("_OPR$")]
DT[, c("ALPHA", "ALPHA_MIN_DATE") := .(max(ALPHA), 
    fmin(as.Date(DATE[as.logical(ALPHA)]))), by = ID]
```

-output

```
> DT
   ID  C_OPR  D_OPR       DATE ALPHA ALPHA_MIN_DATE
1:  1 ABCD01   <NA> 2002-02-02     1     2002-02-02
2:  1 ABCD11   <NA> 2005-05-05     1     2002-02-02
3:  1   <NA>  PQRST 2001-01-01     1     2002-02-02
4:  2   EFGH   <NA> 2003-03-03     1     2003-03-03
5:  2   <NA> EFGHIJ 2004-04-04     1     2003-03-03
6:  2   <NA>   <NA>       <NA>     1     2003-03-03
7:  3   KLMN   <NA> 2001-01-01     0           <NA>
8:  3   <NA>   <NA>       <NA>     0           <NA>
```

---

Or try

```
DT[, c("ALPHA", "ALPHA_MIN_DATE") :=
   {i1 <- Reduce(`|`, lapply(ALPHA_DEF, \(pat) paste(C_OPR, D_OPR) %like% pat))
   .(+(any(i1)), fmin(as.Date(DATE[i1])))}, by = ID]
```

Comment: Thanks again Akrun. Can you please also help me with this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75873940/conditionally-mutate-new-column-based-on-date-interval-and-other-variables-in-da

Comment: I will happily mark my question as solved when it is :)