# conditionally mutate new column based on DATE interval and other variables in data.table R

Tags: r, data.table

I need some help with a quite complex problem, I´ve tried to be as clear as possible.

**Input data:**

```
A<-(c("AA10", "AA20", "AA30"))
B<-(c("BB10","BB20","BB30"))
C<-(c("CC", "DD"))

library(data.table)

DF<-data.table::data.table(
              ID = c(1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,2L,2L,2L,
                     2L,3L,3L,3L,3L,4L,4L,4L,5L,5L,5L),
            DIAG = c("AA10","AA100","AA20","BB10",
                     "BB1000","D05","AA10","AA105","BB10","BB101","AA10",
                     "BB2020","BB2020","BB20","BB10","AA20","AA200","AA10",
                     "AA205","AA305"),
             DAT = c("2001-01-01","2002-02-02",
                     "2003-03-03","2004-04-04","2010-10-10","2011-11-11",
                     "2002-02-02","2003-03-03","2004-04-04","2005-05-05","2001-01-01",
                     "2002-02-02","2003-03-03","2004-04-04","2002-02-02",
                     "2003-03-03","2009-09-09","2001-01-01","2002-02-02",
                     "2003-03-03"),
         OP_DIAG = c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,
                     NA,NA,NA,NA,"CC10",NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA)
    )
```

**Desired output:**

```
     ID  DIAG DAT          OP_DIAG ABAB_MIN_DAT ABAB_MAX_DAT A_DIAG AB_DIAG B_DIAG
 1:  1   AA10 2001-01-01    <NA>   2001-01-01   2010-10-10   <NA>    <NA>    YES
 2:  1  AA100 2002-02-02    <NA>   2001-01-01   2010-10-10   <NA>    <NA>    YES
 3:  1   AA20 2003-03-03    <NA>   2001-01-01   2010-10-10   <NA>    <NA>    YES
 4:  1   BB10 2004-04-04    <NA>   2001-01-01   2010-10-10   <NA>    <NA>    YES
 5:  1 BB1000 2010-10-10    <NA>   2001-01-01   2010-10-10   <NA>    <NA>    YES
 6:  1    D05 2011-11-11    <NA>   2001-01-01   2010-10-10   <NA>    <NA>    YES
 7:  2   AA10 2002-02-02    <NA>   2002-02-02   2005-05-05   <NA>     YES   <NA>
 8:  2  AA105 2003-03-03    <NA>   2002-02-02   2005-05-05   <NA>     YES   <NA>
 9:  2   BB10 2004-04-04    <NA>   2002-02-02   2005-05-05   <NA>     YES   <NA>
10:  2  BB101 2005-05-05    <NA>   2002-02-02   2005-05-05   <NA>     YES   <NA>
11:  3   AA10 2001-01-01    <NA>   2001-01-01   2004-04-04    YES    <NA>   <NA>
12:  3 BB2020 2002-02-02    <NA>   2001-01-01   2004-04-04    YES    <NA>   <NA>
13:  3 BB2020 2003-03-03    <NA>   2001-01-01   2004-04-04    YES    <NA>   <NA>
14:  3   BB20 2004-04-04    CC10   2001-01-01   2004-04-04    YES    <NA>   <NA>
15:  4   BB10 2002-02-02    <NA>   2002-02-02   2009-09-09    YES    <NA>   <NA>
16:  4   AA20 2003-03-03    <NA>   2003-03-03   2009-09-09    YES    <NA>   <NA>
17:  4  AA200 2009-09-09    <NA>   2009-09-09   2009-09-09    YES    <NA>   <NA>
18:  5   AA10 2001-01-01    <NA>   2001-01-01   2003-03-03    YES    <NA>   <NA>
19:  5  AA205 2002-02-02    <NA>   2001-01-01   2003-03-03    YES    <NA>   <NA>
20:  5  AA305 2003-03-03    <NA>   2001-01-01   2003-03-03    YES    <NA>   <NA>
```

**Logic:**

All data is grouped by **`ID`**.

`A_DIAG`, `B_DIAG`, `AB_DIAG`:

All `DIAG` (in same `ID`) are searched to contain values defined in `A` and `B`. If `DIAG` (in same `ID`) only contains `A` values (and not `B`) this should generate `A_DIAG=YES`. Please note that e.g `AA205` is a hit since it **starts with** "`AA20`".

Consequently, if `DIAG` contains only `B` values, then `B_DIAG=YES`.

In cases where `DIAG` (in same `ID`) contains both `A` and `B` values this generates `AB_DIAG=YES.`

However, there are exceptions in cases where `DIAG` contains both `A` and `B` values. If the 5 latest years (counted from the highest `DAT`) only contains `A` or `B` values, this should count as `A_DIAG` or `B_DIAG` and not `AB_DIAG`. This is the case in my sample data in `ID=1` where there is a time span of >5 years between `2010-10-10` and `2004-04-04`, where both dates contains `B` values and followingly,`B_DIAG=YES`.

The other exception is when `OP_DIAG` starts with `CC` (as defined in `C`) AND when there are either `A` or `B` values in `DIAG` (in same `ID`), this should always generate `A_DIAG=YES`.

`ABAB_MIN_DAT, ABAB_MAX_DAT`:

This indicates the lowest and highest date, respectively of either `A_DIAG` or `B_DIAG`.

Anyone eager to help? :)

Preferably data.table solution but dplyr is also welcome as well as other smart solutions.

Best,
H

Comment: I did try this, but got confused with the last 5 year span

Comment: I’ve done my best re-writing the question. Do you still find it confusing? What can I do to make it clearer?

Comment: I am not exactly sure about the conditions.  Here is what I come up `DF[, grp := replace(substr(DIAG, 1, 1), !grepl("^[A|B]", DIAG), NA_character_)];
  DF[, DAT := as.IDate(DAT)];`

Comment: `DF[, A_DIAG := if(any(grepl("^CC", OP_DIAG), na.rm = TRUE) && any(c("A", "B") %chin% grp)) "YES" else NA_character_, ID];
  DF[, year_grp := cumsum(round(as.numeric(difftime(DAT, shift(DAT, fill = first(DAT)), units = "weeks"))/53) >= 5), ID];
  DF[, B_DIAG := if(Reduce("&", lapply(split(grp, year_grp), \(x) "B" %in% x)) & uniqueN(year_grp) > 1) "YES" else NA_character_, ID];
  DF[, A_DIAG := if((Reduce("&", lapply(split(grp, year_grp), \(x) "A" %in% x)) & uniqueN(year_grp) > 1)| "YES" %in% A_DIAG | 
       all(grp == "A", na.rm = TRUE)) "YES" else NA_character_, ID];`

Comment: `DF[, AB_DIAG := if((Reduce("&", lapply(split(grp, year_grp), \(x) all(c("A", "B") %in% x))) & !"YES" %in% A_DIAG)) "YES" else NA_character, ID]`

Comment: Thanks alot Akrun. Unfortunatly i cannot upvote or accept since you answered in comments

Comment: My answer is not complete.  So, i didn't answer as a solution

Comment: Thanks alot for the effort anyway :)

Comment: Regarding the "other exception", you say "defined in `C`", should that be "exemplified for ID `3`"? And how are you using the word "or" there? Because for the 1st exception, you used "A or B" as "exclusively A or exclusively B", but that cannot be the same definition for ID=3 since row 10 has AA10, so it had "A or B" as in "either one can be contained and it doesn't have to be exclusive".

Comment: Yes that is examplified in ID 3. Which should be “AB_DIAG” if it wasn’t for the C, which “overrules” the basic logic. But only if there are A or B present in DIAG which there are in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this implements the desired logic.
Keep in mind that,
according to the example,
the calculation of MIN/MAX dates doesn't care about the exceptions you mentioned.

```
library(lubridate)

# redefine rules as regexp patterns
A <- paste0("^[", paste0(A, collapse = "|"), "]")
B <- paste0("^[", paste0(B, collapse = "|"), "]")
C <- paste0("^[", paste0(C, collapse = "|"), "]")

# base answers that can be adapted for each ID-based group
ans_A <- data.frame(A_DIAG = "YES", AB_DIAG = NA_character_, B_DIAG = NA_character_)
ans_B <- data.frame(A_DIAG = NA_character_, AB_DIAG = NA_character_, B_DIAG = "YES")
ans_AB <- data.frame(A_DIAG = NA_character_, AB_DIAG = "YES", B_DIAG = NA_character_)
ans_NA <- data.frame(A_DIAG = NA_character_, AB_DIAG = NA_character_, B_DIAG = NA_character_)

# helper functions - SD means subset of data

with_min_max <- function(ans, SD, indices) {
    ans$ABAB_MIN_DAT <- min(SD$DAT[indices])
    ans$ABAB_MAX_DAT <- max(SD$DAT[indices])
    ans
}

group_fun <- function(SD) {
    matches_A <- grepl(A, SD$DIAG)
    matches_B <- grepl(B, SD$DIAG)
    
    if (any(grepl(C, SD$OP_DIAG), na.rm = TRUE) && (any(matches_A) || any(matches_B)) ) {
        # OP_DIAG exception
        matches_either <- matches_A | matches_B
        return(with_min_max(ans_A, SD, matches_either))
    }
    
    matches_neither <- !(matches_A | matches_B)
    
    if (all(matches_neither)) {
        # min/max dates also set to NA if no matches for A or B are found
        return(cbind(ans_NA, as.data.frame(rep(list(as.Date(NA)), 2L))))
    }
    else if (all(matches_A | matches_neither)) {
        return(with_min_max(ans_A, SD, matches_A))
    }
    else if (all(matches_B | matches_neither)) {
        return(with_min_max(ans_B, SD, matches_B))
    }
    
    matches_either <- !matches_neither
    max_date <- max(SD$DAT[matches_either])
    years_to_max_date <- as.numeric(as.duration(max_date - SD$DAT), "years")
    is_recent_enough <- years_to_max_date <= 5
    
    if (all(is_recent_enough | matches_neither)) {
        return(with_min_max(ans_AB, SD, matches_either))
    }
    
    matches_neither_recent <- matches_neither[is_recent_enough]
    
    if (all(matches_A[is_recent_enough] | matches_neither_recent)) {
        return(with_min_max(ans_A, SD, matches_either))
    }
    else if (all(matches_B[is_recent_enough] | matches_neither_recent)) {
        return(with_min_max(ans_B, SD, matches_either))
    }
    else {
        return(with_min_max(ans_AB, SD, matches_either))
    }
}

# apply
DF[, DAT := ymd(DAT)][
    , c("A_DIAG", "AB_DIAG", "B_DIAG", "ABAB_MIN_DAT", "ABAB_MAX_DAT") := group_fun(.SD), by = "ID"]
```

I gather from your description that rows that match neither A nor B rules
(like row 6 in your example)
can be essentially filtered out.
For your "5 latest years" case,
the dates of those non-matching rows are also ignored when getting the newest `DAT` from the group.

Comment: Note: this assumes all groups will have at least one match for A or B rules, if some groups may have no matches at all, it needs adjustment.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, some groups may have no matches at all.

Comment: @hklovs ok, I adjusted the code so that it returns `NA` for all new columns in groups where no matches occur.