# select ANY variable in same group - data.table

Tags: r, data.table

Data:

```
DT<-data.table::data.table(
          ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L),
       ALPHA = c(TRUE, FALSE, NA, NA, TRUE, FALSE),
        BETA = c(FALSE, NA, TRUE, NA, FALSE, NA)
)
```

Desired output:

```
    ID ALPHA BETA AB
1:  1  TRUE FALSE TRUE
2:  1 FALSE    NA TRUE
3:  1    NA  TRUE TRUE
4:  2    NA    NA TRUE
5:  2  TRUE FALSE TRUE
6:  2 FALSE    NA TRUE
```

Logic:

If either ALPHA or BETA is true in same ID then AB is TRUE

I´m looking for a data.table solution to solve this simple problem.

Best,
H

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```r
DT[, AB := fcoalesce(any(ALPHA | BETA), FALSE), ID]
#       ID  ALPHA   BETA     AB
#    <int> <lgcl> <lgcl> <lgcl>
# 1:     1   TRUE  FALSE   TRUE
# 2:     1  FALSE     NA   TRUE
# 3:     1     NA   TRUE   TRUE
# 4:     2     NA     NA   TRUE
# 5:     2   TRUE  FALSE   TRUE
# 6:     2  FALSE     NA   TRUE
# 7:     3  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE
# 8:     4     NA     NA  FALSE
```

I added some data that should not match,

```r
DT<-data.table::data.table(
          ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L),
       ALPHA = c(TRUE, FALSE, NA, NA, TRUE, FALSE, F, NA),
        BETA = c(FALSE, NA, TRUE, NA, FALSE, NA, F, NA)
)
```

If you are 100% certain that you will never have an `ID` with at least one non-`NA` value, then you can omit the `fcoalesce` component, relying solely on `DT[, AB := any(ALPHA | BETA), ID]`. Or ... you can do just that, and then follow with `[is.na(AB), AB := FALSE]`.

Answer (score 2):

```
DT[, AB := sum(ALPHA, BETA, na.rm = TRUE) != 0L, ID]
#>    ID ALPHA  BETA   AB
#> 1:  1  TRUE FALSE TRUE
#> 2:  1 FALSE    NA TRUE
#> 3:  1    NA  TRUE TRUE
#> 4:  2    NA    NA TRUE
#> 5:  2  TRUE FALSE TRUE
#> 6:  2 FALSE    NA TRUE
```

This will be fast, and easily expandable to many columns with `.SD`.

```
DT <- cbind(
  data.table(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L)),
  setNames(as.data.frame(matrix(sample(c(TRUE, FALSE, NA), 6*26, 1), 6)), LETTERS)
)
DT[, .(AB = sum(.SD, na.rm = TRUE) != 0L), ID, .SDcols = A:Z]
#>    ID   AB
#> 1:  1 TRUE
#> 2:  2 TRUE

DT <- data.table(
  ID = rep.int(1:1e5, sample(5, 1e5, 1))[1:1e5],
  ALPHA = sample(c(TRUE, FALSE, NA), 1e5, 1),
  BETA = sample(c(TRUE, FALSE, NA), 1e5, 1)
)

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  fcoalesce = DT[, fcoalesce(any(ALPHA | BETA), FALSE), ID],
  sum = DT[, sum(ALPHA, BETA, na.rm = TRUE) != 0L, ID],
  check = "equal",
  times = 10
)
#> Unit: milliseconds
#>       expr      min       lq      mean    median       uq      max neval
#>  fcoalesce 138.6877 141.2975 142.17896 141.82050 143.1662 145.7793    10
#>        sum  27.3827  27.9891  29.23414  29.13795  30.2017  31.5791    10
```

Comment: Thanks alot. Feel free to look into my other problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75873940/conditionally-mutate-new-column-based-on-date-interval-and-other-variables-in-da

Answer (score 1):

Another `data.table` option (with `any` over `.SD`)

```
> DT[, AB := any(.SD, na.rm = TRUE), ID][]
   ID ALPHA  BETA   AB
1:  1  TRUE FALSE TRUE
2:  1 FALSE    NA TRUE
3:  1    NA  TRUE TRUE
4:  2    NA    NA TRUE
5:  2  TRUE FALSE TRUE
6:  2 FALSE    NA TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks Thomas. You are also welcome to look into my other, slightly more complex, problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75873940/conditionally-mutate-new-column-based-on-date-interval-and-other-variables-in-da