# update the dataframe in for loop after passing a list using R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I have a list of `emp.code` which i want to pass through a REST API call. For each name the values are to be saved in a data.frame. How I can pass the list in the loop so that all the outputs are appended to the same data.frame. Here is what I have so far.

```
for(k in 1:length(data$emp.Code)) {
  
  res = GET(paste0("https://urlpart1",data$emp.Code[[k]],"&StartDate=01-01-2023&EndDate=02-28-2023"))

  data = fromJSON(rawToChar(res$content))
  
  data <- as.data.frame(fromJSON(rawToChar(res$content)))
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `lapply` instead of a `for` loop and wrap it in a `do.call(what='rbind', ...)`.

```
res <- do.call(lapply(seq_along(data$emp.Code), function(k) {
  u <- GET(paste0("https://urlpart1", data$emp.Code[[k]], 
                  "&StartDate=01-01-2023&EndDate=02-28-2023"))
  data <- fromJSON(rawToChar(u$content))
  as.data.frame(fromJSON(rawToChar(u$content)))
}), what="rbind")
```

Answer (score 2):

We could initiate a data.frame object and rbind it to the same object in a loop

```
data <- data.frame()
for(k in 1:length(data$emp.Code)) {
  
  res = GET(paste0("https://urlpart1",data$emp.Code[[k]],"&StartDate=01-01-2023&EndDate=02-28-2023"))

  tmp = fromJSON(rawToChar(res$content))
  
  data <- rbind(data, as.data.frame(tmp))
  }
```

Comment: Hi Akrun. Can u help me with a complex problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75873940/conditionally-mutate-new-column-based-on-date-interval-and-other-variables-in-da

Comment: can I add the emp code to that data frame output also